# Допустимо ли ударение звездАм в своем стихотворении по аналогии с Ломоносовским

Tags: стилистика, поэзия

Написал стихотворение, в котором есть такая строка: "Мой путь - сквозь тернии к звездАм". Такое ударение напрашивается для рифмования со словом "дам" в следующей строке "Тем, кто со мной, я руку дам". Я выбрал это ударение по аналогии с Ломоносовской строкой "ЗвездАм числа нет, бездне дна". Понимаю, что это против правил современного русского языка. Допустим ли этот вариант в поэтической речи?

Comment: _Допустим ли?.._ === Если стихотворение хорошее, то допустим.

Answer (score 4):

Разумеется, можно, кто ж вам запретит.

Вы имеете право смещать ударения, писать без знаков препинания или вообще с орфографическими ошибками (для художественного эффекта), выдумывать собственные слова и даже новые буквы.

Вопрос лишь в том, понравится ли это читателю. А вот этого мы за вас выяснить не можем, да и не знаем вашей аудитории: может, это любители Хлебникова, для которых стих без неологизмов скучен, или знатоки Ломоносова, которые узнают вашу аллюзию.

Решать вам. Руководствуйтесь не формальной грамотностью текста, а поэтическим чутьём.

Answer (score 3):

А зачем вообще пытаться проводить аналогии? В то время ударение на последний слог в слове "звездам" было нормальным. То ли дело "правила современного русского языка". 
Вообще, нужно понимать, что есть так называемое *поэтическое* ударение (см. *поэтическая вольность*), то есть *специальное*  для поэзии. Оно возникает, когда поэт переносит ударение для сохранения ритма, тем самым, скорее всего, "нарушая" литературную норму.

Придираться к *звезд**а**м* из-за того, что это "неправильно", глупо. А вот говорить об уместности такого переноса можно.

Comment: Абсолютно согласна с Aer, что во времена Ломоносова  ударение на последний слог в слове "звездам" было нормальным. Но, не зная содержания, тематики и стилистической направленности стихотворения, невозможно судить, насколько будет НУЖНЫМ и УМЕСТНЫМ такой перенос.

Answer (score 0):

Конечно, допустим. Поэтам разрешается смещать ударение в целях сохранения ритма. Вспомним стихотворение Ф.И.Тютчева "Silentium!":

*Встают и заходЯт оне// Безмолвно, как звездЫ в ночи...*

Правда, надо признать, что на эту особенность произношения слова сразу обращаешь внимание, и не всегда это нравится...

Comment: Тютчева я бы не брал в пример. Стилистика стихов у него ужасная. Но вот содержание очень интересное, заставляющее порой закрыть глаза на эти недочёты.

Comment: Ужасная? Простите, но вынуждена решительно возразить. Великий поэт заслуживает восхищения. Стихотворения Тютчева совершенны как по форме, так и по содержанию. Неслучайно о его сборнике А.Фет сказал: "Вот эта книжка небольшая томов премногих тяжелей". Тютчев был самым придирчивым критиком своих стихов и безжалостно выбрасывал в корзину написанное, если его что-то не устраивало в стихотворении.

Comment: Согласен с Фетом. Тютчев был мастером вместить объёмные мысли в миниатюрной форме. Но афористичность его отдельных строк, не отменяет того, что вокруг этого афоризма текст уровня среднего графомана. Отглагольные рифмы, чрезмерные архаизмы,  порой нарушение ударения и грамматики. Все это искупается оригинальным содержанием, что но не отменяет тривиальность формы.

Answer (score 0):

Поэтам, как известно, дозволено всё. Но далеко не всё поэтам следует себе позволять. Из этого и исходите.

Оправдан ли такой прием - это уже от контекста зависит. "Аналогия" - термин, конечно, не удачный. Но если стиль стихотворения в целом предполагает архаизм или обращение к классике, то да. В остальных случаях лучше сто раз подумать.